ReferenceError: self is not defined in nextjs
I am working on downloading the html as pdf in next.js project.
So, I used html2pdf.js package.
This is my code.
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

const pdfJSX = () => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1 className='text-[red] text-[40px] font-strawford'>JSX to PDF Convert Example</h1>
            <img src='/new-b2c/onboarding/image.png' className='w-[50px] h-[50px]'/>
            <h2>Hello React</h2> 
          </>
        )
    }

    const handleConvertToPdf = async () => {
        const printElement = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(pdfJSX());

        var opt = {
          margin: 0.5,
          filename: 'myfile.pdf',
          image: { type: 'png', quality: 1 },
        //   html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
          jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        };       

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(printElement).save();        
    };

But I got an error here like this.
"ReferenceError: self is not defined".
image description
I tried to solve the issue with several methods.
But I can't solve this error.
I think, this part has an issue.
html2pdf().set(opt).from(printElement).save();   

So, how can I solve the issue?

I believe you need a default export

Could you explain in more detail?

import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

// If this is a react component in a nextJS route you need a component to be a default export

export default const pdfJSX = () => {
        return (
          <>
            <h1 className='text-[red] text-[40px] font-strawford'>JSX to PDF Convert Example</h1>
            <img src='/new-b2c/onboarding/image.png' className='w-[50px] h-[50px]'/>
            <h2>Hello React</h2> 
          </>
        )
    }

    const handleConvertToPdf = async () => {
        const printElement = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(pdfJSX());

        var opt = {
          margin: 0.5,
          filename: 'myfile.pdf',
          image: { type: 'png', quality: 1 },
        //   html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
          jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
        };       

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(printElement).save();        
    };

